# C++ expression must have pointer to object type error

Tags: c++, pointers

I am new in c++. I was working on Matrix.

I have source.cpp, It is include;

```
#include "Matrix.h"

/*******************************************************
* Test1
*******************************************************/
void Test1(){
    Matrix M;
    double A[] = { 8, 2, 4, 6, 3, 5, 2, 7, 4 };
    double B[] = { 1, 5, 8, 3, 5, 6, 4, 7, 9 };
    double C[9];,
*
*
*
```

My matrix.cpp class include;

```
void Matrix::Add(double *A, double *B, double *C, int N){ 
    for (int i = 0; i<N; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j<N; ++j)
        C[i][j] = A[i][j] + B[i][j];
}
```

But I am getting

> "expression must have pointer to object type"

error on C,A and B. What should I do?

Comment: You should read this:  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Neither `A`, `B` or `C` are matrices, they are simple arrays and therefore you can't treat them as an array of arrays like you want to do.

Comment: `Matrix` wants 2-d array but `A`, `B`, `C` is 1-d array.

Comment: I think the best course of action is to step back in the c++ tutorial, and read about data types and about pointers. Then about object programming and classes. The code examples you show kinda suggest that you are a bit far in the wrong direction. It is probably easy to "fix" you `Matrix::Add` but it would only reinforced the wrong path.

Comment: One would expect `Matrix` to represent a matrix, and `Matrix::Add` to either add another `Matrix` to `*this` or return a new `Matrix` that is the result of adding another `Matrix` to `*this`, not to add two arrays into a third array, all of which are unrelated to the `Matrix`

Comment: Since you are new in C++, here is one important thing about C++: Don't use arrays if you can avoid it. Arrays lead to bad stuff if not controlled. Use std::vector instead. Can do everything an array can, deletes it's memory on it's own and has several useful methods, like size() and dynamic size change.

Answer (score 0):

in matrix::add, you have 3 parameters of double*, which are single pointer to double values.

In your function, you treat them as double** (A[x][y]), which are pointer of pointers of values.

If you want to this work, you have to calculate the ID of the array in one bracket : `C[i+j*N] = A[i+j*N] + B[i+j*N];`

**Note :** A very good library which handles vectors (2,3 and 4 dimensions) and matrix. [look at GLM Library](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.7/index.html)